# Saving into SQLite while parsing with Beautiful soup

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I am scraping real-estate data, which works very well. However, I have some issues/uncertainties with the storing of the data. I do not want to upload all my code here - I hope that's fine. Basically, my approach looks as follows:

In a first step, I create an sql-databse using the package **sqlite3**.

The actual scraping has the following form:

```
for zip_code in list_zip_codes:
   conn = sqlite3.connect('some_name.db')
   if zip_code_di == zip_code:
      ...
      scraping
      ...
   conn.execute('''INSERT INTO...
   else:
      conn.commit()
      conn.close()
```

For each object I'm pulling, I get a zip-code, which is named zip_code_di here. What I would like to do is to commit the data as soon as the zip-code changes (that's why I use the if-else condition). Does this approach make sense to you? Is there a better/more common way to make sure all the data is stored?

Comment: conn.commit() makes sense, yes. However, you don't need conn.close() until the script ends. If you leave your script as it is you will need to re-connect to the database for each new zip-code you encounter.

Comment: @ Bill Bell. Thank you very much for your feedback. So the commit makes sure the data is stored after each iteration? The loop takes very long to run through. This is why I want to make sure that the data is not lost due to an interruption error for example.

Comment: You're right, that's what the commit is meant to do. I understand your purpose, it makes sense.